# Java DocumentBuilderFactory.parse(); returning null document

Tags: java, xml, null

When I call `DocumentBuilderFactory.parse(xml-file-path);`, it returns a null document. I am 100% sure that the file path for the document is right.My full code is as follows:

```
public static boolean readXML(String xml) {
    Document dom;
    // Make an instance of the DocumentBuilderFactory
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        // use the factory to take an instance of the document builder
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        // parse using the builder to get the DOM mapping of the
        // XML file
        dom = db.parse(xml);

        System.out.println(dom + " " + xml + " " + dom.getElementById("1"));

        Element doc = dom.getDocumentElement();

        System.out.println(doc);

        address = getTextValue(address, doc, "address");
        System.out.println(address);
        return true;

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        System.out.println(pce.getMessage());
    } catch (SAXException se) {
        System.out.println(se.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.err.println(ioe.getMessage());
    }

    return false;
}
```

and

```
XMLReaderWriter.readXML("C:\\Users\\username\\eclipse-workspace\\project\\src\\preferences.xml");
```

Preferences.xml is simply:

```
<address>idk just filler for now</address>
```

The return I get is:

[image: error]

Why is it returning a null document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't give you a "null document", it gives you exactly the document you provided. *address* is your only element and is therefore treated as the document root element. The *toString()* method of your element object prints element name and element value. Since *address* is an element node, not a text node, the value is always *null* (element nodes don't have values, only child nodes). To get the contained text, you either have to get it's direct child, which is a pure text node, or use getTextContent().

```
System.out.println(doc);
System.out.println(doc.getFirstChild());
System.out.println(doc.getTextContent());
```

will print

```
[address: null]
[#text: idk just filler for now]
idk just filler for now
```